# Rails3 & Git & Heroku - development/staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I have a Rails 3 app I'm developing with a team using Git/Github and deploying to a Heroku cedar stack. Our Github respository has 2 main branches Master and Development.

I would like to push our Development branch regularly to a different server on Heroku as a development/staging environment.

What's the cleanest simplest way to push our Development branch to a different app than Master without disrupting our Git flow much?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to add a second git remote i.e. your second application's heroku git repo url to your app to be able to push to that from a single codebase.

At the moment you probably have the default remote origin named 'heroku' which is pushing to your production application.

You'll want to add a second remote origin pointing at your new heroku app that you intend to use for staging, eg

```
git remote add staging <git repo url from 'my apps' page on heroku>
```

once you have the new git origin set up you can push to it via;

```
git push staging <branch to deploy>:master
```

Comment: Ok cool, I like this route for now. I added a second app and pushed it live. Now my only question is, to be very careful, how do I know which app i'm talking to when i run `heroku <anything>` stuff from the command line?  Like if i want to do `heroku run rake db:seed` how/why does it know which app i'm talking to?  thanks much

Comment: pass it explicitly along with the command, eg `heroku run rake db:seed  --app <heroku app name>`. Note, it's the app name as it appears in 'My Apps' on heroku not the remote origin name.

Comment: Here's an old blog post I wrote on exactly this subject - http://john.beynon.org.uk/developing-with-multiple-environments-on-hero

Comment: if you don't want to specify --app every time, you can run `git config heroku.remote <remote_name_here>`, and after that, heroku will use whichever remote you specified by default when you run heroku commands without --app, until you switch it to a different remote.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.  Heroku always uses the master branch, but using Git will allow you to push /your/ development branch, to /their/ master

For instance:

```
git push heroku development:master
```

where `heroku` is your origin for your heroku development env, and `development` is your local development branch.  You might also want to override the `RACK_ENV` var on Heroku too if you don't want your dev branch running in production mode (although, personally I would create a staging environment in your code which does caching etc, but not send email to production addresses etc)

Comment: You can accomplish similar configs by having your `config/environments/production.rb` set up certain config options based on environment variables, and then set up your Heroku config vars differently per staging/production apps.

Answer (score 0):

[heroku_san](https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san) is a Gem which allows complex deploy configurations when using Heroku, without the need to constantly specify which Heroku app you wish to push to on the command line. It would allow you to do exactly what you describe above.

Comment: I plan on using that or at least checking it out in the near future. It looks pretty sweet. Thanks.